# Private message values not inserting

Tags: function, mysqli, sql-insert, pgp

I'm having trouble inserting my values from one page into another and then into the database its showing no errors either which is rather puzzling and not inserting into the database. 
I pass the values over from a form via ajax and all the values needed are being sent over so I presume it has something to do with the values sent over from pminsert. Database is included and all my values are safe from sql injection. I've just put the needed code below.

pminsert

```
if($_POST['pmtoid']==$_SESSION['id']){  
        user_core::pmmessage("1",$_POST['pmfromid'],$_POST['pmtoid'],$_POST['pmnewmsg'],"../pm.php?id=".$_POST['pmtoid']."&id2=".$_POST['pmfromid']."",$date);
}else{
        user_core::pmmessage("3",$_POST['pmfromid'],$_POST['pmtoid'],$_POST['pmnewmsg'],"../pm.php?id=".$_POST['pmfromid']."&id2=".$_POST['pmtoid']."",$date);  
}
```

user_core::pmmessage

```
public function pmmessage($typeids,$creatorids,$targetusers,$contents,$url,$date){
    global $mysqli;
    $contents = $contents;
    //$content =  strip_tags($content);

    if($contents>0){ 
        $date=date('y:m:d H:i:s');
        $insertmessage = "INSERT INTO messages(message_type_id,message_creator,message_target,message_content,message_throughurl,message_time) VALUES ($typeids,$creatorids,$targetusers,$contents,$url,$date)";
        $add_message = mysqli_query($mysqli,$insertmessage)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli,$insertmessage));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure auto-commit was enabled, else don't forget to commit or you'll never see your data updated. That would explain why there is no errors.

Comment: What does auto commit do @Jean-franois Savard?

Comment: It commit the data at each modification. In your case, you never commit so if auto-commit is not enabled, this is why your data are not updated even if there is no errors.

Comment: I got it working. I had been a noob and misspelled some words within my query. It took me to go to work and come back to run over it again and find the error. 
Thanks again. And Auto commit is enabled. :D